# Is there a way to stop the fread function to change the value of a string?

Tags: c

In my code, for some reason, the value of a string is changed after the fread function is called.

I have a string variable name "firstNameAux", it value changes after the `continua = fread(registro, 20, 1, arquivoAux);` function is called.

Here's the example when I type "Viniciusopa" as the value: [Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4q7j.png)

```c
void pesquisarNome(void){
    FILE * arquivo;
    FILE * arquivoAux;

    arquivo = obterArquivo("rb");   
    arquivoAux = obterArquivoAux("rb");

    char registro[20];
    char firstNameAux[11];
    char firstName[11];
    char posicao[9];
    int continua;
    printf("What is the name that you're searching for? ");
    scanf("%s", firstNameAux);
    printf("firstNameAux value before the fread: %s\n",firstNameAux);

    do
    {
        continua = fread(registro, 20, 1, arquivoAux);
        printf("firstNameAux value after the fread: %s\n",firstNameAux);
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++){
            firstName[i] = registro[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
            posicao[i] = registro[i+11];
        }
    }while(strcmp(firstNameAux, firstName) != 0 && continua);

    fclose(arquivo);
    fclose(arquivoAux);


}
```

The function obterArquivo return a file with the opening mode equals as the parameters, like this:

`arquivo = fopen("Arquivo", modoAbertura);`

Content of the "arquivo": a          a          a          a               a               a  a         a              22222      ViniciusopaViniciusopaa               a               a  a         a

Content of the "arquivoAux":a          67       a          0        Viniciusopa93

Note: Yes, the little circle at the end is a [Emoji!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU5CK.png) for some reason, this also happens to my friend's computer.

Comment: The code is incomplete, hence it's not possible for us to feed it to a compiler or debugger. Don't assume that users here want to read your code and discover bugs. They want to apply their skills, that include using a debugger, for example.
I feel justified in merely saying that strings must be `\0` terminated, and I assume you didn't check for that.

Comment: The full code is quite extensive, is there a problem if I send it? Sorry for causing trouble, I'm new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Change all the arrays to `[32]`, and try again.

Comment: No, you should add the minimal amount of code that is sufficient to run the code, while the problem should still be reproducible. So you add a very basic `main` function, and then a minimal version of the other functions that are dependencies of this code.

Comment: Most likely, you are reading too much data into another variable, thereby invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: OP's reading too much with the very first `scanf`, if OP is entering "Viniciusopa".

Comment: As others have mentioned your char buffers are overwriting each other. If you plan to use a char buffer for str* functions like strcmp() you need to have a null terminator, which means an 11-character buffer can hold 10 values plus a 11th null (0x00) value. C won't stop you from overrunning your buffers. You can write to contiguous memory until some corruption causes a crash or you hit a memory address you're not able to access. Your buffers are most likely allocated in contiguous stack memory so when you overrun one it's overwriting another.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is exactly that, I changed the maxvalue to 12 and it worked! Thank you guys for the help, sorry for causing trouble.

Comment: Changing the size of the buffer is 12 is a good first step, but you also need to add a width modifier on the conversion specifier in scanf and check the return value.  eg: `char firstNameAux[12]; ... if( scanf("%11s", firstNameAux) == 1 ) ...`

Answer (score 1):

The error was that "Viniciusopa" was taking all the space in the char FirstNameAux, leaving no space for the "\0".

Thanks for: Cheatah, user338619, Jonathan Leffler and Pat9RB